# css file still not loading

Tags: css

I'm still having problems with loading the style sheet for these pages. Works fine in Safari but ff and IE, no joy:
http://www.mainstayprojects.com/teardrop.html andb
www.mainstayprojects.com

Although i am more clear as to what's causing this problem, thanks the the answers to my previous posting ([stackoverflow.com/questions/3273655/css-file-not-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273655/css-file-not-loading)), I am at a loss to how to fix the issue. I have re-saved many times with different doctypes and content type meta tag as well as saving the file as a charset=utf-8 file but have not been able make any headway!

Really need some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server is still claiming the HTML document is ISO-8859-1 (although the document itself looks like UTF-8).

Meanwhile the stylesheet appears to be UTF-8, the server fails to state what encoding it is, and the first line of the stylesheet claims that it is UTF-16.

1. Pick an encoding
2. Configure your editor to use it
3. Configure your server to specify it
4. If you put any information about the encoding at the document level — get it right!

Comment: Thank you David. Can I ask how you determine what the server is clainming?

Comment: I use `lynx -head http://example.com`, but there are plenty of tools out there that let you examine HTTP headers, including Firebug.